# Passing variables within vba macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call a subroutine from two different macros. I have created a standalone macro named `Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow)`.

I have two other macros that define nrow differently. One is meant to append data to the end of the list; the other one replaces data in a given row.

I can duplicate the code in `Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine` in the two macros, but was trying to avoid that.

The first macro (Store_Policy_Info) works fine and passes nrow to the subroutine. The second macro stops on the first line of code in the subroutine:

```
Range("A" & nrow).Value = Range("InsuredName")
```

with

> run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error

It seems it doesn't like having nrow defined in more than one place.

```
Sub Store_Policy_Info()
'
' Store_Policy_Info Macro

Sheet10.Select
Dim nrow As Integer
nrow = Range("nrow").Value
Call Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow)
Sheet1.Select
Range("A1").Select
Sheet10.Visible = False
End Sub

Sub Rerun_Portfolio()
'
' Rerun the entire portfolio in the data tab and replace existing saved outputs

Sheet10.Select
Dim nrow As Integer
nrow = 2
Do While nrow <= Range("nrow")
    Range("RetrievalSelection").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Stored_Inputs"), nrow)
    Call Retrieve_Inputs
    Call Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow)
    nrow = nrow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the  [Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) of `nrow` in `Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow)`?

Comment: There is no problem with having the same name defined in several places, it is only a pointer to a memory location after all ... however, unless nrow is a defined name, the line nrow = Range("nrow").Value will throw an error.

Comment: Would you please validate my understanding: The error is coming out of this line: `Range("A" & nrow).Value = Range("InsuredName")` which is part of the `Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow)` procedure. is this correct?

Comment: My best advice would be to start by giving them different variable names to help clear up your confusion. Just because Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow) takes a parameter called nrow, doesn't mean that's what is has to be called in the other methods, just in that one. It could be named xyz in another method, and called by saying Call Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(xyz).

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Scott Holtzman - nrow is an integer, but the data type is not defined in Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow).

Comment: Bob Phillips, thanks. nrow=Range("nrow") does work because the first macro successfully executes and calls the subroutine. The second macro with nrow <= range("nrow") seems OK, too because it makes it to the 2nd call statement and errors out at the subroutine.

Comment: EEM, yes, you are correct.

Comment: justkrys, I tried changing nrow to mrow in Rerun_Portfolio (except not the range("nrow") which refers to a named range in the workbook. I still get the came error.

Comment: Why you are not posting the procedure that gives the error? You need to publish the procedure `Store_Policy_Info_Sub_Routine(nrow)` otherwise we have nothing to work with...

Comment: EEM, sorry, I am still not very familiar with the process out here. I did post the first line of the procedure (where I get the error).  It is very lengthy and repetitive which is why I didn't post the rest of it. Anyway, I figured it out. I had to move my sheet10.select statement between the two call statements in the rerun_portfolio macro. Thanks for trying to help and sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to move my sheet10.select statement between the two call statements in the rerun_portfolio macro. Thanks for trying to help and sorry for any inconvenience.